# How to achieve parallax effect using CoordinateLayout.Behaviour?

Tags: android

I want to achieve parallax effect of toolbar circular image like
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCP-b0a1x5Y
in this video. But I want this by using CoordinateLayout.Behaviour class. Any help regarding custom behaviours?

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.vats.vatishs.materialdesignlayouts.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.vats.vatishs.materialdesignlayouts.ImageViewBehaviour" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is my code:

```
public class ImageViewBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<ImageView> {

public ImageViewBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, ImageView child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, ImageView child, View dependency) {
    /* What should i do here so that the image (that is displayed on the start of toolbar) will be moved along with toolbar expanded and fit on the center of appbar when toolbar is fully expanded? */
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `ImageView` inside of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and give it `layout_collapseMode="parallax"`. Note the `ImageView` is the first child so it will be drawn behind the `Toolbar`. Use a fixed dimension for the height instead of `wrap_content`, or you can use `match_parent` since your `AppBarLayout` specifies a fixed height already.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout ... >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        ... />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        ... />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: Acually I want to move image for toolbar's top left corner (when toolbar is of action bar size) to the center of app bar layout (when toolbar expand)

Comment: @VatishSharma In that case please revise your question to be more clear. When you use the term "parallax", people think you mean the background of the AppBar in the video you linked to. The image you are referring to isn't being parallaxed, it is being scaled and translated.